# backlog settings of puma similar to unicorn?

Tags: heroku, unicorn, puma

Unicorn accepts a `listen` configuration that allows to set a `backlog` in ms in case the worker is busy. Reducing this value allows the router to send the request to another worker if its busy.

Is there something similar for Puma? I could not been able to find such thing.

This would be extremely handly on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported. You can pass a query parameter to bind that has the `backlog` value.

Here is an example of how to do it in a Rails app.

```
# config/puma.rb
workers Integer(ENV['PUMA_WORKERS'] || 3)
threads Integer(ENV['MIN_THREADS']  || 1), Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 16)

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup

port = Integer(ENV['PORT'] || 3000)
backlog = Integer(ENV['PUMA_BACKLOG'] || 20)

bind "tcp://0.0.0.0:#{port}?backlog=#{backlog}"

environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # worker specific setup
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
                Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool'] = ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 16
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

Note: Make sure you're using a recent version of Puma. I've verified this works in 2.8.2.

[Here is an example app](https://github.com/mscoutermarsh/puma_heroku_example) using this config, I've tested it on Heroku.

For more info, I've added the solution to my blog here: http://mikecoutermarsh.com/adjusting-pumas-backlog-for-heroku/